# Preserve environment variables in Jenkins between Windows build commands

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I am trying to set up Jenkins to continually check out and build code and verify that the code is compilable.

Our build system works like this: we have several different .bat files that set up environment variables for different build configurations, and then we execute gmake to actually build the code.

When I created Jenkins job, in Build part of the job I set up two "Execute windows batch command" commands: one that calls the script to set up env. variables, and gmake to build it.

Problem is, when gmake step runs, all environment variables are forgotten. How can I prevent env. variables from being cleared?

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set it up to call only one bat file instead?  That one file can then call the two you're currently calling with Jenkins.

Comment: The Execute Windows Batch field has complete support for windows batch files, and environment variables are naturally preserved between commands

Comment: Ah, I see, so you ended up using one Execute Windows Batch step to call the two different batch files instead of doing it in two steps like before?